How does one go from wavefunctions to fields?
The original motivation for the Klein-Gordon equation
$$(\square + m^2)\varphi = 0$$
and the Dirac equation
$$(i\hbar\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - mc)\psi = 0$$
were such that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ were to be interpreted as wavefunctions. Of course, it was quickly found that $\varphi$ cannot be interpreted as a wavefunction as it failed to represent a probability amplitude.
What I am unclear on is how one goes from viewing $\varphi$ or $\psi$ as wavefunctions to fields. For example, in quantum field theory texts they use the same equations to discuss $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as fields, but what justifies this change of view? Does anything have to be done for $\psi$ to be a Dirac field instead of a Dirac wavefunction?
This change of view happens before any quantization occurs, so I am led to believe this is simply a change of view and there is nothing more to it. Is this correct?
Note I have already read this similar post, but the answer only describes the difference between a wave function and field and not what justifies the change in point of view.

The classical fields require continuous observation of many quanta. The classical electromagnetic field can only be measured if we are constantly emitting and absorbing photons, i.e. quanta of electromagnetic field energy. Even then not every effect becomes classical. Planck radiation is, for instance, never classical. It always gives away that we are dealing with field quantization. In many cases there is no such thing as a classical field, to begin with. The electron field does not really have a classical mean field theory.

There is a fundamental difference between fields (quantum or not) and corresponding wavefunctions.
A wave function has only positive energies when expanding it in modes, a field solution has both positive and negative energies.
This difference has a crucial impact on the notion of localisation. Relativistic wavefunctions contrarily to fields cannot be localised in space at fixed time. This is a source of all difficulties in defining the notion of position for a quantum relativistic particle.
(All that generalises to QFT in curved spacetime even in absence of a preferred notion of energy, but this discussion would be a bit technical and I prefer not to describe it now.)
When passing to second quantization the object to promote to an operator is a field and not a wave function in the relativistic theory.

(+1) Could you elaborate in more detail regarding the fermion wavefunction, i.e. Dirac's equation, please? In particular, the Dirac equation does have both positive and negative eigenvalue solutions, right? Then, is the Dirac equation a "wavefunction" or a "field"? If it's not yet a field, then what should be added to the Dirac equation to make it a classical field (pre-second-quantization)? Lastly, $\Psi(x,y,z,t)$ seem to have an explicitly defined distribution over the position coordinates $x, y,z$, what did you mean exactly by it "cannot be localized in space at fixed time"? Thank you.

The wavefunction of an electron is a solution of Dirac equation with only positive energies. It is possible to prove that there are not such solutions which vanish outside a bounded set in space at given time. In the space of positive energy wavefunctions the standard “position operator” is not the correct notion of position observable. The apparently correct one is the Newton Wigner one which is however affected by several pathologies concerning its interplay with causality.

To pass to a field you should add a negative energy part to the Dirac wavefunction, obtaining a general solution. This complete object can be “second quantised” and the negative energy part turns out to describe positrons (but taking anti commutation rules into account)

Thank you very much. I am still a little unclear about what you meant by "wavefunction of an electron". I did calculate the plane wave Dirac solution ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4941235/why-do-numerical-eigenvector-computations-turn-out-different-compared-to-symboli ) and both positive and negative eigenvalues show up in the list of eigenvalue solutions. Could you specify what is the calculation for the "wavefunction of the electron", please?

When you add the modes there are factors  $e^{i(px \pm t E(p))}$. In a field solution both types of modes take place, in a wavefunction only the modes with $-tE(p)$ are considered.

Thank you! To make sure I have understood your answer correctly, mathematically nothing changes, that is the equations remain unchanged when $\psi$ is viewed as field instead of a wave. It is only our interpretation that changes (which is why we're ok with negative energies appearing, for example).

The equations remain unchanged, but wavefunctions are a special type of field: solutions of the field equations made of positive energy modes only. This restriction is not assumed for fields.

@ValterMoretti I see, so for example for a solution to the Dirac equation $\psi$ the field interpretation would keep all components of $\psi$, but the wavefunction (as in relativistic quantum mechanics) would only keep the first two components since they correspond to positive energies?

Yes, you have understood.

@ValterMoretti Thanks for all the help!

You are correct that there is no mathematical change in viewing them as classical fields instead of quantum wave functions.  It is only our perspective on what they are useful for that changes.  They are useful for creating quantum operators, rather than for describing wave functions.  When we quantize, we create operators that obey the same equations as the classical field equations but with the additional property that they also obey canonical (anti)commutation relations.

(+1) could you elaborate what exactly is encoded in the anticommutation relation, please?

The anticommutation relation applies to Fermionic fields (like Dirac fields), and says that the anticommutator of a field and its canonical momentum, at equal times, is equal to i times hbar.  The anticommutator of two operators A and B is AB + BA.  For a Dirac field Psi, the canonical momentum is i times the Hermitian adjoint of Psi.

thank you. would it be correct to say that the primary purpose of the anticommutator {a, a+}=1, {a,a}=0, {a+,a+}=0 is to algebraically enforce a+a+ = 0, i.e. Pauli exclusion?

It's hard to say what the primary purpose is.  But yes, the Pauli exclusion principle is a direct consequence of anticommutation of field operators.

It is not just a change of view. Although there are cases where the field and the wave function represent more or less the same thing, in general they represent two different things. Apart from the differences in their formal description in terms of the formalism, there are also conceptual differences. Here, I'll focus on the conceptual aspects.
Starting with fields, one can remind ourselves that classical fields are solutions of the equations of motion. In the quantum case, one finds that the equations of motion are often the same as those for the classical fields. However, we also have the Schroedinger equation for the quantum wave functions. The difference is that, unlike in the classical case, quantum states can consist of multiple excitations (I'm avoiding using the term "particles"). Each excitation can be seen as a solution of the equations of motion and carries a full compliment of all the degrees of freedom. These solutions are the fields, as discussed above. Therefore, wave functions in general consist of multiple fields. The way Weinberg phrased it is to say that wave functions are functionals of fields.
